# Scala closing over val when asking

Tags: scala, akka

I want to know if the following code will close over the id value in the ask 'callback' in the map function.

```
val id = if (model.id.isEmpty) UUID.randomUUID().toString else model.id
val result = couchbaseActor ? SetDoc(s"user:$id", model.toJson.compactPrint)
   result map {
      case true => sender ! Right(Success(id))
      case false => sender ! Left(makeFailureFromErrorEnum(ErrorCode.DbSaveFailed, List("User", "Error occurred while saving to Couchbase")))
  }
```

Thanks, Aaron

**Eventual Solution:**

Message Handler:

```
case SaveUserReq(model) => saveDocument[User](sender, "User", model.id, model)
```

Definition:

```
def saveDocument[T:JsonWriter](requester: ActorRef, prefix: String, id: String, model: T): Unit = {
  couchbaseActor ? SetDoc(s"${prefix.toLowerCase}:$id", model.toJson.compactPrint) map {
    case true => requester ! Right(Success(id))
    case false => requester ! Left(makeFailureFromErrorEnum(ErrorCode.DbSaveFailed, List(prefix, errorCouchbaseSaveFailed)))
  }
}
```

Thank you to all who assisted.

Comment: Why not simple `if(result)` by the way?

Comment: Fair call, but the question remains.. Do I need to send the id back in the response, or will the id val be safe to use in the map/if section?

Comment: I do like the code style of the map/match syntax though, and saves any kind of asInstanceOf or mapTo casts. I guess I just find it easier to comprehend, but I am open to reasons for/against as it is still early days with me in scala and I still need to pick up a preferred style

Comment: You are closing over `model`, probably over `this` when calling `makeFailureFromErrorEnum` and over `ErrorCode`. In addtition to that, you are closing over `sender`, which is even worse, because sender is a `def`. Is your `model` a `def`, `val`, `var` or `object`? The same goes for the `id` inside.

Comment: Thanks @agilesteel, I updated the question as I had incorrectly `Right(Success(model.id))`. The model is a case class matched in the receive def matched as such:`case SaveUserReq(model) => `. What's the catch with closing over sender..? Sounds like I may need to refactor this..

Comment: Thanks everyone.. Turns out my `val id` is safe because I `val`'ed it and I either need to `val` my sender, or pass it into a def where the code body will live because method parameters are also `val`'s. Hats off to this post which led me down the right path [http://helenaedelson.com/?p=879](http://helenaedelson.com/?p=879)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**sender/getSender() disappears when I use Future in my Actor, why?**

"When using future callbacks, inside actors you need to carefully avoid closing over the containing actor’s reference, i.e. do not call methods or access mutable state on the enclosing actor from within the callback. This breaks the actor encapsulation and may introduce synchronization bugs and race conditions because the callback will be scheduled concurrently to the enclosing actor. Unfortunately there is not yet a way to detect these illegal accesses at compile time.

Read more about it in the docs for Actors and the JMM"

- http://akka.io/faq/

Answer (score 2):

1. Well, I think that `id` is used as is. It is a constant, isn't it?
2. Victor Klang gives the source of error: the access to `sender` method of `this` actor. Your code actually looks like

   ```
   val id = if (model.id.isEmpty) UUID.randomUUID().toString else model.id
   val result = couchbaseActor ? SetDoc(s"user:$id", model.toJson.compactPrint)
   result map {
     case true => this.sender.tell(Right(Success(id)), self)
     case false => this.sender.tell(Left(makeFailureFromErrorEnum(ErrorCode.DbSaveFailed, List("User", "Error occurred while saving to Couchbase"))), self)
   }
   ```

   It seems that it closes over `this`.

   Probably rewriting the code the following way:

   ```
   val id = if (model.id.isEmpty) UUID.randomUUID().toString else model.id
   val theSender = sender
   val result = couchbaseActor ? SetDoc(s"user:$id", model.toJson.compactPrint)
   result map {
     case true => theSender ! Right(Success(id))
     case false => theSender ! Left(makeFailureFromErrorEnum(ErrorCode.DbSaveFailed, List("User", "Error occurred while saving to Couchbase")))
   }
   ```

   can help.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it should

By definition of a closure

Comment: Does that mean the code is not safe, that the id value could have changed by the time the dispatcher handles the ask response? Or is the id/state somehow picked by the dispatcher responsible for handling the ask response and everything is ok..?

Comment: @atom.gregg If you use `val`s and operate on immutable values, it's impossible for a value of `id` to change over time. In other words, it's safe if you stick to functional programming practices.

Comment: Hi Nikita, I was thinking that another thread/message may come through between the first and second call, so the id val would be relevant to the new threads execution. My comprehension of closures needs some work.. Thanks in advance.

Comment: the 'id' you are refering to is a _val_ and therefore a snapshot of model.id or UUID.randomUUID() when executed. It cannot change afterwards. 
(Though iff model.id and UUID.randomUUID both would return a function/object with apply function and the true case would cause the execution of the apply you could potentially have different result depending on time passed. But this seems not relevant here and you are not using id twice)